# dblib выдаёт знаки вопроса вместо русских букв

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, кодировка, yii

Все русские символы из бд приходят знаками вопроса

```
 <?php
    $db = new yii\db\Connection([
    'dsn' => 'dblib:host=192.111.11.114;dbname=name',
    'username' => 'us',
    'password' => 'pas',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
                         ]);
              
    $result = $db->createCommand("EXECUTE get :prod")
              ->bindValue(':prod_sn',$SN)
              ->queryAll();
     ?>
```

/

```
echo mb_detect_encoding($result[$i]);
```

здесь говорит что кодировка ASCII

```
mb_convert_encoding($result[$i], "ASCII", "UTF-8");
```

Кодировку после этого не меняет

Подскажите где туплю?

Comment: Если вам пришли знаки вопроса - значит данные уже безвозвратно уничтожены. Нужно исправлять проблему в том месте, которое заменяет русские буквы на знаки вопроса. Вы уверены, что в БД действительно лежат именно русские символы, а не знаки вопроса?

Comment: да. так как когда подключаюсь через sqlsrv

$db = new yii\db\Connection([
    'driverName' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dsn' => 'sqlsrv:Server=192.111.11.114;Database=name',
    'username' => 'us',
    'password' => 'pas',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
]);

всё приходит кириллицей, и в строках где кирилица - UTF-8 кодировка,в остальных так же ASCII

Comment: Значит просто подключайтесь через это, в чём проблема тогда?

Comment: нет возможности подключиться через sqlsrv..
на хосте драйвер невозможно установить